# efficient way to get timestamp relative to current date in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, timestamp

I need to calculate dates based on distance in days and also months from today. I need to return it in the format mm/dd/yyyy. Using VBScript's DateDiff function you can only get the distance in days (or months, or minutes, or years, I know) from a date. So of course you can clumsily piece together a timestamp knowing all these. Is there a more efficient way of calculating the timestamp of a day 7 days ago? 1 month ago? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `DateDiff`, but `DateAdd` to add date to today. Then use a dotnet `StringBuilder` to easily format your date (works better than building your own format functions and you are more flexible):

```
' initializing
myDate = Now
monthsToAdd = 6
daysToAdd = 15
myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

' shifting the date
myDate = DateAdd("m", monthsToAdd, myDate)
myDate = DateAdd("d", daysToAdd, myDate)

' formatting the date 
Set sb = createobject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
sb.AppendFormat "{0:" & myFormat & "}", myDate

' passing the result
WScript.Echo sb.ToString()
```